# dynamic text in <h1> tag

Tags: seo

what would be the impact on SEO of changing the text of the `<h1>` dynamically on the server side each time the web page loads?

I'm not talking about changing the whole text, just part of it, for example if the header contains some fixed text (with keywords of course), and also contains the current date or time/the current number of logged on users/the count of items current in stock/whatever.

how would that affect my ranking? is it bad? doesn't make a difference?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't think that element you need should be H1, since semantically, H1 is most important heading on a page which can but shouldn't contain anything that isn't of crucial importance like that number of logged in users o time.

Personally, i would use H1 just for important heading which contains important keywords.

Otherwise, you can put wanted H1 and perhaps a Paragraph and put them in a DIV altogether for such purpose where paragraph contains content irrelevant to page and still harness the value of a H1 and content you want in virtually the same spot.

Comment: I agree, and that's also what I told our development teams here, but still I was asked that question :)
so, the recommendation to separate dynamic text from the H1 tag is accepted, yet I would like to know what kind of impact it has if it remains there.

Comment: perhaps loosing of context?
one of big errors that people make while building websites is that they give undescriptive titles and headings which don't go with the flow of what page is actually about.

Don't know really but i don't think it could bring any benefit to a website rankings.

maybe this could help:
http://wantedtext.com/change-wordpress-h1-seo-dynamic-post-title

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic text in H1, but you need to make sure that no duplicates is allowed. Its not recommended to have duplicate H1 across the site.
You can use dynamic text in H1, but make it a template based.

For Example: If you have categories in your shopping cart and want to display the name of the category in H1...follow a templated structure like

"category-name | Keyword or Company Name"

By doing so, you do not have duplicate tiles, and can achieve uniform structure across the site

Similarly for product pages

"category-name | product-name | Website Name or Company Name"

If you have a long titles with dates and numbers and query string, format in a way which can be read by users and searchbots, and remember the semantics

Comment: This answer as it stands is not good, it does not explain the impact of adding s1 tags dynamically on SEO, please consider revising it.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that h1 tags affect SEO is far from being a myth, but with SEO evolving the way it is, it's becoming fairly useless. It's the same thing with meta information and such practices: after the [Panda and Penguin](http://www.imediaconnection.com/content/33314.asp), and other reforms Google is making right now, all SEO methods that are easy to abuse of are becoming less and less important for being ranked in Google. Back in the day people could rank at the top by repeating a keyword hundreds of times on a page, in the same way that properly written h1s ranked sites very well. We're far from those times now, Google is aware of the fact that people can abuse of these simple practices, so anything from h1 text, to meta, and even to backlinks, is taking less importance in search engines by the day.

Rather than focusing on h1s, which you shouldn't be putting much effort in, focus on writing good content, and on updating that content as frequenly as possible. Good luck :)